# Detect element and click this element on tag <canvas> in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, canvas

The website only has one tag is  it contains all element.

I want to click on an element in this canvas.

I tried with code:

```
public void ClickCanvas(QA.IWebElement wbCanvas, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        QA.Interactions.Actions actionBuilder = new QA.Interactions.Actions(wd);
        Actions hoverClick = actionBuilder.MoveToElement(wbCanvas).MoveByOffset(x, y).ContextClick();
        hoverClick.Build().Perform();
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

And I use this function:

```
var width = int.Parse(browser.FindElementById("easCanvas").GetAttribute("width"));
var height = int.Parse(browser.FindElementById("easCanvas").GetAttribute("height"));
for (int i = 0; i < height; i += 5)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j += 5)
    {
        browser.ClickCanvas(browser.FindElementById("easCanvas"), j,i);
    }
}
```

It scans at browser only centre of the screen. Must start at Point(0, 0) of the screen instead of start at the centre of the screen.

And I don't know when an element is clicked.

RESOLVED:

In selenium document,

> moveToElement(WebElement toElement) : Moves the mouse to the **middle of the element**.
>
> moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset) : Moves the mouse to an offset from the top-left corner of the element.

There is the reason for my question:

> It scans at browser only centre of the screen

I need at position `(0, 0)` to it start at begin of an element.

Should be changed to:

`Actions hoverClick = actionBuilder.MoveToElement(wbCanvas, 0, 0).MoveByOffset(x, y).ContextClick();`

> And I don't know when an element clicked.

In my site, I test when clicking on the element it will open a new popup, this popup is contained `<iframe>` tag.

I need add code:

```
while(browser.FindElementById("iframe_D") == null)
     Thread.Sleep(50);
if(browser.FindElementById("iframe_D") != null)
     browser.GoToFrame(browser.FindElementById("iframe_D"));
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This may be weird, but try using a minus y figure and see what happens.

It worked for me recently on one of my projects.

Comment: @VănLộc I mean to say change the 'y' figure to minus. i.e. if y =56 change it to -56

Comment: I was changed to x, -y, or to -x, -y, or -x, y

Comment: Try all combinations and report back @VănLộc

Comment: Thanks, @marwaha.ks : I updated my question. The problem is `moveToElement(WebElement toElement) `: Moves the mouse to the middle of the element. I need to add `(0, 0)` to know it should start at begin of the element.